# Can't Get Count of viewControllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to iterate through the controllers that my UITabBarController is managing, and for the tabs that have UINavigationControllers contained therein, see how many viewControllers are currently on the navigation stack. Unfortunately, while the controllers claim to be UINavigationControllers, and their viewControllers property appears to be an array, it doesn't respond to "count" as I'd expect:

```
    for ( UIViewController *controller in tabBarController.viewControllers ) {
    if ( [controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] ) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)controller;
        NSLog(@"Analyzing controller: %@", controller.title);
        NSLog(@"Views in hierarchy: %@", [navigationController.viewControllers count]);
    } else {
                ....
            }
    }
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the "Views in hierarchy:" line when it tries to send the count message to navigationController.viewControllers.

I'm baffled here, and would love any help anyone can offer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `%@` format specifier to print out the result of `-count`, which returns an `NSUInteger`. `%@` is suitable only for printing out objects, and so it'll be expecting an object even as you provide it only an integer. You'll have to do something like this instead:

```
NSLog(@"Views in hierarchy: %lu",
    (unsigned long)[navigationController.viewControllers count]);
```

Comment: Why the cast to unsigned long? count already returns a NSUInteger, which on iPhone is an unsigned long.

Comment: @Guillaume That's an implementation detail. If it happened to be another type, it would no longer match the `%lu` format specifier.

Comment: Oh, right you are. <blush> I've clearly been staring at this stuff too long. Thank you!

Comment: doesn't explain why you casted it. The method count of the class NSArray returns an NSUInteger, and you are casting it to the same (on iPhone) type. That's unnecessary, and could be harmless if later you modify this code. If it happened to be another type, you would use an other format specifier.

Comment: @Guillaume `NSUInteger` is defined specifically so that we can be ignorant of its actual type. Its actual type will depend on the characteristics of the target system (for instance, 32 or 64 bit). Casting to `unsigned long` is a good way to preserve most or all of its precision while making it a known type.